# Sharing on facebook and twitter from my metro app

Tags: c#, facebook, xaml, twitter, microsoft-metro

I am working on a metro app and want to share something on Facebook and twitter. But in metro sharing their is source and target app concept. Source app is mine but how should I get Facebook and twitter as target app.

Answer (score 0):

Before you share something to Facebook or Twitter, first you'll need to connect your Facebook account to Windows 8 using the People app(already installed on your Windows 8)

You can find more details here: http://windows8tipstricks.com/connect-facebook-account-windows-8-people-app/